# JFrame not popping up when I input the correct login credentials

Tags: java

I'm a beginner who's trying to learn java and currently I am in the process of trying to scan elements from a text file.

Whenever I try to input the correct login credentials (that is also saved in the text file) my JFrame that says: Successfully Logged in should pop up, but unfortunately, it's not.

I have no idea where should I try to fix it, whether it's on my JFrame or scanning algorithm

Here's my source code, below it is my JFrame informing the user that they have successfully logged in.

```
else if (e.getSource() == buttonLogin){

        boolean isFound = false;
       
        String line = "";
        String[] database = new String[100];
        String username = textFieldUsername.getText();
        String password = passwordFieldPassword.getText();

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("accounts.txt"));
            // algorithm that will scan the txt file
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                database = line.split(",");
                if (username.equals(database[0]) && password.equals(database[1])) {
                    System.out.println("Confirmed");
                    isFound = true;
                }
            } // end of algo
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        // event triggers if boolean is set to true
        if (isFound){
            new SuccessfulLoginDialogue();
        } else {
            new UnsuccessfulLoginDialogue();
        }
    }
```

JFrame

```
public SuccessfulLoginDialogue(){

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,200);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(panel);

    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(52,73,94));



    label.setBounds(40,10, 250, 100);
    label.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    label.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 15));
    panel.add(label);


    confirmButton.addActionListener(this);
    confirmButton.setBounds(100,100,90,21);
    confirmButton.setBackground(new Color(46,204,113));
    panel.add(confirmButton);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == confirmButton){
        frame.dispose();
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Generally, your Swing application has one and only one `JFrame` and as many `JPanels` as necessary.  Edit your question with a [mre] that we can compile and test in our IDE for better help.

Comment: Understood, I will try to do that

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).